# Perforce recovery from version files

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to recover a perforce depot where you only have the version files? The server where perforce was running on has crashed and is not currently running. Can I recovery from this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely hard and generally impossible, because critical information is stored in the Perforce server's database tables, which are separate from the version files.

But why not restart the Perforce server? Why did it crash, and why is it not currently running?

It sounds like you need to get in touch with Perforce Technical Support.